# new data inserted in the middle rows accident

Tags: mysql, insert, row

I just insert a data with a form in my website, normally the data will inserted  in the last of rows like :
auto_increment name

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

but, when i insert a new data last time, it inserted in the middle rows of table, looked like :

```
17 data17
30 data30
18 data18
19 data19
20 data20
```

the newest data that has been inserted in the middle rows of table (data30).
it's happen to me rarerly (still happen) why this happen? and how i prevent this thing in in the future? thankyou.

Comment: why is this a problem? Why not just sort by ID when you get the data back?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718229/stop-mysql-reusing-auto-increment-ids) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the result returned by the engine. It is hardly a matter which recod is fetched early and which later as it depends on a lot of issues. For one, dont think your database table to be a sequential file like FoxPro. It is way more sophisticated than that. Next, for every query that returns data use a Order by clause to avoid these instances.

So always use:

```
select columns from table order by column
```

The above will ensure you get the data the way you need and not be surprised when the DB engine finds a later record in cache while fetches an older record from a slow media in another database file. If you read the basics of RDBMS concepts then these things are discussed as also you need to study how MySQL internally works.

I found this great article that discusses the many wonderful features of a modern database query engine.
http://thinkingmonster.wordpress.com/mysql/mysql-architecture/

Although the entire article discusses the topic very well but you may pay extra attention to the section that talks about `Record Cache`.