# Newly created instance takes the primary id of a deleted instance with same Account name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of users in a table. When I delete a User and then create a user with the same account name, it takes the primary id of the deleted user.

The problem with this is, though a user is deleted, I keep track of what all users are deleted. When a new user takes the primary id of a deleted user, I have two instances with same primary id in my table.

I want the primary id to be different from the old one.

How do I do it?

Comment: Which rdbms are you actually using? What's the table structure?

Comment: Your tags suggest at least three different flavours of RDBMS.  As this appears to be an implementation problem you need to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior of `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields in MySQL:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,167180

If this is really your problem, you will have to find an other strategy to keep track of deleted user accounts.

For more information, see [Stop MySQL Reusing AUTO_INCREMENT IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718229/stop-mysql-reusing-auto-increment-ids)