# MySQL unexpectedly re-using deleted auto increment values

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment, amazon-rds

I'm running MySQL server 5.6.21 on Amazon RDS Multi-AZ with InnoDB tables and I'm experiencing behaviour that should not be occurring according to what I've read in the documentation.

MySQL is re-using auto increment values when the highest auto increment value is deleted. For example let's say I have a table with these auto increment values in use: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. If value `5` is deleted, then MySQL is re-using it upon the next insert.

From reading all the relevant MySQL documentation I can see, this should not be possible except if the server is restarted. The server is not being restarted and I can see no explanation for this behaviour.

It's causing serious problems for my application which references the assigned auto increment values in other places for auditing. The way MySQL should be behaving according to the docs is exactly how I need it to behave. I've searched all over the internet and can't find anyone else who is experiencing this specific issue. I have a feeling this is something to do with RDS / replication but I can't find anything that would explain this.

Relevant MySQL server settings:

> auto_increment_increment = 1
>   auto_increment_offset = 1
>   innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1

I've narrowed down the cause to exclude the insert statements that are re-using the values. This is because if I delete the row with the highest auto increment value (let's say it's `5`) and then immediately check the next auto increment value by viewing the information schema, it will say `6` as expected. However, if I wait a few seconds/minutes and then refresh the information schema, the next auto increment value will suddenly change to `5` with no other queries being run!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deleted values can be reused if new rows are inserted specifying a deleted Id. Are you sure that isn't happening something similar?

Comment: @genespos - sorry I should have said, on all inserts the auto increment value is not being specified in the query

Comment: Is your auto-increment column a part of a multi-column index? Because [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3718578/5629218) might apply.

Comment: @Lav - That is very interesting and not something I was aware of. Unfortunately this is not the case though. The auto increment id value is not part of any multi-column indexes in my tables.

Comment: Please turn on the "general log" and rerun your test where it "suddenly changes to 5".  Then turn off the general log (to avoid filling up the disk) and see what, if anything, is in that log.  Also check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime%';` to see verify that there was no restart.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the suggestion, I will update here as soon as I've been able to give that a go